# How Do I Conditionally Concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a',0]})
>>> df
  col
0   a
1   0
>>> df['col'] = 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)
>>> df
    col
0  stra
1  str0
```

I want to do the above, but only if df['col'] meets 2 conditions, namely length of value == 4 and value in column matches one of a list of options.

Apologies if this has been asked before, I have been searching for days and can't find anything comparable.

Comment: Using .loc and isin

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm unsure how to build the statement.

Comment: `df.loc[(condi1)&(cond2),'col']='str' + df['col'].astype(str)`

Comment: I get the following error


`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy`

Comment: @acecabana Please, provide example input and output that you want to get

Answer (score 1):

```
# The list of options
l = ['aaaa']

# The filtering conditions
cond_1 = df['col'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 4)
cond_2 = df['col'].isin(l)
```

Then, as @Wen pointed out:

```
# The manipulation.
df.loc[(cond_1 & cond_2), 'col'] = 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. What ended up working was making a copy of the df prior to running the code. The error no longer appeared. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method for that. Here is example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['abcd',0]})
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str)

df['col'] = np.where(df['col'].str.len() == 4, df['col'] + 'b', df['col'] + 'a')
print(df)
#     col
# 0 abcdb
# 1    0a
```